# Animation(move Image) to right edge of Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, canvas

I have a page,page have canvas,in canvas exist image,and exist animation.
Animation(beginning on datatrigger) must move image from Canvas.Left to ActualWidth of Canvas.
It's easy at first sight :) but...
Binding don't wokring,im trying to solve this for 2 days (((
I have two solutions for this problem, but none is complete.

**Solution 1: DataTrigger - Working. Binding "To" - Don't woking.**

```
 <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="EnemyAnimation" Storyboard.TargetName="Xenomorph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="0"  To="{Binding ElementName=Canvas1,Path=ActualWidth}" BeginTime="0:0:3"  Duration="0:0:10" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding startAi}" Value="true">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource EnemyAnimation}" />
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Canvas x:Name="Canvas1" Margin="20" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Image x:Name="Xenomorph1" Height="100"  Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/Mathilvania;component/Resources/Xenomorph.gif" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,65,0,0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                </Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ContentControl.Template>
    </ContentControl>
```

**Solution 2: DataTrigger - I can't add DataTrigger. Binding "To" - Working**

```
<Canvas Name="canv" Margin="50,0,100,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="100">
        <Image x:Name="Xenomorph" Height="100"  Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/Mathilvania;component/Resources/Xenomorph.gif" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Canvas.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.SizeChanged">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetName="Xenomorph">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                    BeginTime="0:0:1"
                    Duration="0:0:5"
                    From="0"
                    To="{Binding ElementName=canv, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Canvas.Triggers>
    </Canvas>
```

In Solution 1,i can't Binding "To" but trigger working.
In solution 2 Binding work,but DataTrigger,i can't add

## UPDATE:

When i add DataTrigger to Solution2 like this:

```
 <Canvas Name="canv" Margin="50,0,100,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="100">
        <Image x:Name="Xenomorph" Height="100"  Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="/Mathilvania;component/Resources/Xenomorph.gif" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Canvas.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding startAi}" Value="true">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetName="Xenomorph">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                    BeginTime="0:0:1"
                    Duration="0:0:5"
                    From="0"
                    To="{Binding ElementName=canv, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Canvas.Triggers>
```

I have an erron:

Elements of the Triggers family must have the type EventTrigger

Comment: In your second example, the animation will start over and over again as soon as the `Canvas`' size changes. Is this a desired behavior?

Comment: I used this to show the work of Binding to the dynamically changing value of TO,but i can't add DataTrigger ,i have error about "...Must EventTrigger bla bla bla" I do not remember exactly

Comment: Error like this:
Elements of the Triggers family must have the type EventTrigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty common problem. You can use the data bindings for the `From` and `To` properties of an animation only if it is not in an `ControlTemplate` or a `Style`. In these cases, the `Animation` needs to be sealed (frozen), that's obviously not possible if some its properties change their values dynamically.

There is a workaround solution for this. It isn't neat, but it works. You just have to introduce an intermediate scale factor that you'll be animating with a hard-coded `Animation`. But the actual value will be then calculated using a multiplying `IMultiValueConverter` on a `MultiBinding`.

Here is an example.

The converter could look like this:

```
public class MultiplyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values.OfType<double>().Aggregate(1.0, (current, t) => current * t);
    }

    // ConvertBack omitted...
}
```

And in XAML, you can use the `Tag` of your object for holding the animated scale factor.

Something like this:

```
<Canvas x:Name="Canvas" xmlns:l="Your_converter_namespace" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Canvas.Resources>
    <l:MultiplyConverter x:Key="MultiplyConverter"/>
  </Canvas.Resources>
  <Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Blue">
    <Rectangle.Style>
      <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAnimationStarted}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
              <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
                <Storyboard TargetProperty="Tag">
                  <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:5"/>
                </Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
              <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="Storyboard1"/>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>  
      </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
    <Rectangle.Tag>
      <sys:Double>0</sys:Double>
    </Rectangle.Tag>
    <Canvas.Left>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiplyConverter}">
        <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="Canvas"/>
        <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
      </MultiBinding>
    </Canvas.Left>
  </Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```

You'll see that resizing the `Canvas` won't cause the animation to start over again, but rather it will seamlessly continue.

Comment: Thank you, I saw this solution before, but I want to avoid it, because I did not understand it :)

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it's a nightmare :)
I do not lose hope to finding other solutions